# Breaking up long equation with lots of parentheses -- can't get rid of errors

Tags: math-mode

I have read all answers that use `align`, `multline`, `multlined` etc. but I cannot get rid of errors in my case. Also, the use of `\left.` and `\right.` does not eliminate errors. Any help appreciated. The use of automatic `\left` and `\right` generates horribly high left parenthesis and anemic right ones, therefore all the visual pairing is gone down the drain, so I posted a second equation using `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`, which looks a lot better IMHO. But the errors from breaking the line in two are still there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

%lower the subscript by ex points
\def\dc{\rule{0pt}{1.0ex}}
\def\dd{\rule{0pt}{1.5ex}}
\def\df{\rule{0pt}{1.8ex}}
\def\ds{\rule{0pt}{2.0ex}}
\def\dss{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}
\def\dds{\rule{0pt}{3.0ex}}


\begin{document}

This is a very long equation...
\\
%\begin{align*}
\begin{multline*}
\leqslant\;
\sum_{j \,=\, 1}^{m}
%\left\Bigg\{\,
\left\{\,
\sum_{i \,=\, 1}^{n}
%\Bigg[\,
\left[\,
\int\displaylimits_{\ds{Z_{\dc{i}}}}{
%\Bigg(\,
\left(\,
%
% first norm
\Big\Vert\, 
K
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\;-\;
K_{i}
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\,\Big\Vert
% end first norm
\;+\;
\right.
\right.
\right.
\\
\left.
\left.
\left.
%
% second norm
\Big\Vert\, 
K
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\;-\;
K_{i}
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\,\Big\Vert
% end second norm
\,\right)
\,\mathrm{d}\lambda} 
%\,\Bigg]
\,\right]
%\,\Bigg\}
\,\right\}
\;\leqslant\;
%\end{align*}
\end{multline*}
\\%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{align*}
\leqslant\;
\sum_{j \,=\, 1}^{m}
\Biggl\{\,
\sum_{i \,=\, 1}^{n}
\Biggl[\,
\int\displaylimits_{\ds{Z_{\dc{i}}}}{
\Biggl(\,
%
% first norm
\Big\Vert\, 
K
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\;-\;
K_{i}
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\,\Big\Vert
% end first norm
\;+\;
\right.
\right.
\right.
\\
\left.
\left.
\left.
%
% second norm
\Big\Vert\, 
K
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\;-\;
K_{i}
\Big(\,
\mu
\big(\,
\omega(A_{\dd{j}})
\,\big)
\,\Big)
\,\Big\Vert
% end second norm
\,\Biggr)
\,\mathrm{d}\lambda} 
\,\Biggr]
\,\Biggr\}
\;\leqslant\;
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) why all those manual spacing commands? (2) all those left right constructions are useless anyway because even split using the dot construction you are likely to get un even scaling. My advice would be to start by removing all those left right constructions and go from there. I cannot test your code as I'm on a tablet. BTW it will be helpful to others if you cite the error you get.

Comment: BTW with all this manual adjusting you are doing, you are really going to piss off journal editors who has to make sure things are up to the journal standard.

Comment: You are starting from the false premise that you have to say `\int\displaylimits_{<domain>}{<integrand>}`. You should use `\limits` and ***no*** braces around the integrand. Of course the result, due to all those `\big` and spaces is completely wrong, from a typographic point of view.

Comment: @egreg I tried \limits first, it did not align the expression equally/simetrically under the integral sign, instead it put all of it to the lower right of the integral. \displaylimits_ seems to do a better job for some reason, especially when you have under the integral a larger expression, like [ a, b ] for example. Thank you for the tip with the integrand, that was the problem really! I took out those curly braces around the integrand and all errors went away.

Comment: Since you *are* in a display, `\limits` and `\displaylimits` behave in exactly the same way. But that's not the main problem, just a question of style. The syntax error disappeared, yes, but the typesetting ones didn't. Please, leave TeX most of the math typesetting and don't be too generous with delimiter sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is in using

```
\int\displaylimits_{<subscript>}{<integrand>}
```

where the braces around the integrand are useless (and are the cause of your troubles.

Also `\limits` is sufficient and, of course, all that manual sizing and spacing produces a bad result.

In order to have openings you have to use `\bigl` and for closing `\bigr` (with the obvious variants). Moreover you're choosing too big sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

This is a very long equation...
\begin{multline*}
\leqslant
\sum_{j=1}^{m}
\biggl\{\, % this \, is good, because of \sum following
\sum_{i=1}^{n}
\biggl[\, % this \, is good, because of \int following
\int\limits_{Z_i}
\Bigl(
% first norm
\bigl\Vert 
  K\bigl(\mu(\omega(A_{j}))\bigr)-K_{i}\bigl(\mu(\omega(A_{j}))\bigr)
\bigr\Vert
% end first norm
+{}\\
% second norm
\bigl\Vert
  K\bigl(\mu(\omega(A_{j}))\bigr)-K_{i}\bigl(\mu(\omega(A_{j}))\bigr)
\bigr\Vert
% end second norm
\Bigr) \,\mathrm{d}\lambda
\biggr]
\biggr\}
\leqslant
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

There is no reason for the fences to fully cover what they delimit.

[image]

Comment: is there a reason you use `\bigl\Vert` and \bigr\Vert` rather than `\big\lVert` and `\big\rVert`?  (the results are the same, as they appear on my screen.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, they are not the same: with `\bigl\Vert` I get an Open atom; with `\big\lVert` I get an Ord atom. It's similar to `\left\|`, which is the same (but simpler to type) as `\left\lVert`.

Comment: Why is there a need for +{}\\ instead of simply +\\? The +\\ compiles fine and it looks exactly the same as +{}\\ on my machine...

Comment: @Diegis Not *exactly*.